# Setting context root does not work in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am specifying a context root as the XML below shows. It does not work however when I upload the war file manually in the Glassfish admin web console. If I deploy it through the maven plugin for glassfish it works. It seems like Glassfish does not read the file and use the default name...Am I missing something or is this (yet another) a bug? I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 build 5.

*glassfish-web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
    "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>myContextRoot</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is an issue of Glassfish. The admin web console have an own text field for the context root which will be  auto filled with the name of the war file not his config. When you hit the deploy button this value overwrites the context-root from your config file. But the asadmin deploy and all plugins ant, maven ... are working OK.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. So far I found no official explanation. I assumed it to be a bug.

Comment: Besides that, the undeployed module still show up in the managmeent ui, unless you restart the browser.  This should be another bug.

Comment: I am having the same issue too. running glassfish6.2.3 web profile, using maven, and jdk17.

Comment: 10 years later the bug still exists I am now running glassfish 7.0.9 JDK 21 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS why isn't this bug fixed yet?