# What does Context Root mean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

I am deploying a simple web module to **glassfish** server.

The package name is `test2.war`.

The runtime deployment descriptor file `sun-web.xml` specifies the `Context Root` as below:

```
  <context-root>/myTest</context-root>
```

According to the Java EE 5 tutorial, `A context root identifis a web application in a Java EE server.` I expected that I should visit my site like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/myTest
```

But it turns out I still have to use:

```
http://localhost:8080/test2
```

So what's the purpose of Context Root? How to use it?

### ADD 1

According to [Setting context root does not work in Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491203/setting-context-root-does-not-work-in-glassfish)

This seems to be a glassfish bug.

Comment: This may contain the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216323/using-the-context-root-from-glassfish-web-xml-in-glassfish-3

Comment: well, does the sun-web.xml is still supported (and loaded) in a glassfish server? Haven't seen such files in apps for some time...

Comment: @PeterMmm Thanks. I followed that thread and turn to use `glassfish-web.xml`. It works now.

Comment: @maslan I am new to Java. Maybe I am not reading the latest info.